# Coloring houses with 4 colours

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am stuck on this question:

> What is the number of possible arrangements of N houses in a circle given that no two consecutive houses can have the same color (red, green, blue or white)?

Can anyone give me any tips on how to solve it?

Comment: yeah was trying out with permutation ...got a couple of base cases bt then lost track . when there are 3 houses i get 24 and for 2 houses i get 12 ..

Comment: @Blender : no. of colors given is always 4 for any n ,so (red,green,red,green) ,dis is also a valid combination if n=4 houses

Comment: Can you explain that once more? Is `red, green, red, green` the order of the houses, or the colors that you can use>

Comment: This belongs on math.stackexchange.

Comment: @Blender: N->No. of houses,colors with which u can color the N houses is 4(red,green,blue,white),ie.You can use any subset of it to color the houses such that NO two consecutive house has same color and the starting and ending house also have different colors as they are arranged in circle.any color can from within those 4 can be used any number of times bt no consecutive houses can have same color

Comment: @TanmoyPatra: This should be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring

Comment: for n=2 ->ans 12 ;n=3 ans 24 ; n=5 ans 240

Comment: Here's a duplicate of your question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91009/prove-that-the-chromatic-polynomial-of-a-cycle-graph-c-n-equals-k-1n

Comment: @Blender: thanks it was pretty cool stuff # problem solved  :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give it a try: Number Of possible arrangements = (number of permutations) - 4*(all have the same color) - 4*(number of combinations of adjacent 3 houses in 4 elements) - 4*(number of combinations of 2 houses in 4 elements)

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring u can get it here